# ibus-libpinyin input not working in fullscreen emacs

Tags: input-method, gtk3

I'm using GTK emacs 26.3 on GNOME 3.34 using X.

When emacs is fullscreen, ibus-libpinyin is unable to render the pinyin suggestions. Input seems to still be working (i.e when I press a number a chinese character appears) but the suggestions fail to appear.

This problem doesn't happen when emacs is not full screen.

Any ideas?

As a side note, rendering works when firefox is full screen, so the problem is not in all full screen apps.

Comment: I'm using emacs 27.2 and gnome 3.38.5. Seems like it will get [fixed](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/ibus-candidate-panel-sometimes-not-shown-above-fullscreen-motif-app/6832) in 3.38.6 which is just released today.